# Where to find MySQL InnoDB Cluster Names

Tags: mysql, mysql-innodb-cluster

Where can I find the cluster names that have been created in an InnoDB cluster when the cluster isn't running?

Comment: have you tried `mysql-js> var cluster = dba.getCluster()
mysql-js> cluster.status()`

Comment: The cluster isn't started and I need  the cluster name to be able to start it.

Answer (score 1):

The cluster name is registered in the Metadata schema. A simple SQL query can be used to obtain it:

```
SELECT cluster_name from mysql_innodb_cluster_metadata.clusters;
```

However, if you need to reboot your cluster from complete outage, you don't need its name.

The command `dba.rebootClusterFromCompleteOutage()` can be used without the `clusterName` parameter. If you see its documentation you'll notice that the `cluster_name` parameter is optional. This is because multiple Clusters cannot belong to the same Metadata schema.

So to recover your cluster, connect to one of its previous members and run:

```
mysql-js> var cluster = dba.rebootClusterFromCompleteOutage()
```

More information at: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-innodb-cluster-working-with-cluster.html#reboot-outage

Cheers,
Miguel